# mysql-python static linking on Linux 64-bit

Tags: python, mysql, linux, 64-bit, static-libraries

Has anyone tried to statically link mysql-python with mysql client library on 64-bit Linux?

```
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.o /home/apy/MySQL-
python-1.2.3c1/mysql-5.1.42/i/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.a -L/home/apy/MyS
QL-python-1.2.3c1/mysql-5.1.42/i/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lpthread -lcrypt -lnsl -
lm -lpthread -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/_mysql.so
/usr/lib64/gcc-lib/x86_64-suse-linux/3.3.4/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/a
py/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/mysql-5.1.42/i/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.a(libmys
ql.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a sha
red object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/apy/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/mysql-5.1.42/i/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

See also: [mysql-python: building a completely standalone _mysql.so on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966322)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set `CFLAGS="-fPIC"` environment variable. ([reason](http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2004-October/005227.html))
2. Pass `--disable-shared` to `./configure` (besides `--enable-static`, that is) when building mysql.